# Java DOM How to check if node exists in XML

Tags: java, xml, dom

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<productlist>
<product>
<title>1</title>
<price>30</price>
</product>
<product>
<title>2</title>
<price>9</price>
</product>
<product>
<title>3</title>
</product>
</productlist>
```

What I need to do is use Java DOM API to print out all the contents from XML file which contain "price" tag.  Such things like this

```
title:1
price:30 
title:2 
price:9
```

In the org.w3c.dom documentation I only find hasAttribute(String name) method to check if this element have attribute but I can not find method like "hasTag(String name)" in documentation.  I find this website http://www.java-forums.org/xml/62136-check-whether-xml-tag-exists-while-parsing-xml-using-dom-java.html but unfortunately I can not open the site.  Hope you can help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just call [`getElementsByTagName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) and see if the returned list has any nodes (using `NodeList.getLength()`).

Comment: seems this is the best way, little bit tricky anyway. But thanks